# How to manipulate array data received from ajax call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, function

So I am trying to populate a few cards from bootstrap with the information I get from an ajax call, the function for the call works and it's being logged so I can see the array of information coming back, now my question is how would I go about making that array I receive into a new array I can work with? possibly the var newPeopleArray?

> ```
> function startUp() {
>
>         console.log("startup is running");
>         getPeople()
>     }
>
>     //var newPeopleArray = ?????????
>
>     var getPeople = function () {
>
>         var url = " TOOK OFF FOR THIS ";
>
>         var settings = {
>             cache: false
>             , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
>             , dataType: "json"
>             , success: (function (data) {
>                 console.log(data, "success!")
>             })
>             , error: (function () {
>                 console.log("error");
>             })
>             , type: "GET"
>             , headers: { 'TOOK': 'OFF' }
>         };
>
>         $.ajax(url, settings);
>     }
>
>     var renderNames = (peopleArray) => {
>
>         for (let myIndex = 0; myIndex < peopleArray.length; myIndex++) {
>
>             const currentName = peopleArray[myIndex];
>
>             console.log(currentName)
>         }
>     }
> ```

This is what I get back from the call

> ```
> {item: {…}, isSuccessFul: true, transactionId: "6b155adf-4d2b-4beb-850d-d5405ec345a3"}
>      item:
> pageIndex: 1
> pageSize: 5
> totalCount: 1000
> totalPages: 200
> pagedItems: Array(5)
> 0: {gender: "female", name: {…}, location: {…}, email: "christine.reyes@example.com", dob: "1982-06-21 02:25:03", …}
> 1: {gender: "male", name: {…}, location: {…}, email: "keith.morgan@example.com", dob: "1956-10-14 23:19:29", …}
> 2: {gender: "female", name: {…}, location: {…}, email: "carolyn.jensen@example.com", dob: "1979-01-08 10:26:48", …}
> 3: {gender: "female", name: {…}, location: {…}, email: "kathryn.silva@example.com", dob: "1980-07-19 11:36:25", …}
> 4: {gender: "female", name: {…}, location: {…}, email: "georgia.parker@example.com", dob: "1991-04-08 12:50:27", …}
> length: 5
> ```

I just want to get the name, email, and dob from the array that I get back and either make a new array which would be ideal or is there a way to fill up a bootstrap component with information directly from the ajax call?

Sorry if I don't make much sense with my question, pretty new to programming so sometimes it's hard to even ask a question. Thanksyoufor any help!

this is the only thing I have for the actual website from bootstrap

```
<div class="main container">

    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card first" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="" class="card-img-first" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 ">
            <div class="card second" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="" class="card-img-second" alt="">
                <div class="card-body second">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 ">
            <div class="card third" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="" class="card-img-third" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text"> make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I never knew I could be triggered by someone putting commas in front of the items in their arrays.

Comment: Are you using jQuery for your page design?

Comment: It's not clear, but I think you just need to call `renderNames(data)` from the `success:` function.

Comment: @Jhecht hey I updated the question and posted the html part of what I have written down. Sorry about the commas it autosaves it like that, a lot of stuff on VS bothers me that it does by itself but havent figured out how to change those

Comment: Since you haven't tagged any front-end framework that will handle json responses, at some point you should probably be parsing the response by doing something like `let result = JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: @LucasO Can you update your question with the full **JSON** response that you get from the **`XMLHttpRequest`** call?

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving JSON back as a string, then you will need to parse it back into shape.

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse( data );

//  example usage of the JSON object
if ( jsonData[0].gender === "female" ) {
    let firstGender = 1;
} else {
    let firstGender = 0;
}
```